# S3 bucket policy for user facing websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

All the articles out there especially the aws docs list out that it is pretty dangerous to have a public bucket and rightly so but in case of a customer facing platform, for example a social media website, the goal here is to indeed have the assets available to the public and only allow write to **authenticated users on the platform**.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is that users are only allowed to write to the bucket if they have been granted access using the [presigned POST urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) but users are allowed to read from a specific location in the bucket.

I've got a specific policy in mind but would this allow anyone to write to the bucket?

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Write",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "bucket_name/path/path/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "bucket_name/path/path/*"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: The First Statement Allow Anonymous to PutObject onto bucket_name/path/path/*  . This is Public write

Comment: If you are using pre-signed URLs for uploads, then the bucket policy does not need to permit `PutObject`. The pre-signed URL is sufficient. If you wish to make objects accessible to anyone in the world, you can use the second part of your bucket policy, but use `"Principal": "*"` (without the `AWS` bit).

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein that indeed does look like a plan, let me try this out and get back to you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

By default S3 private buckets only allow private access for write interactions, the first statement allows `PutObject` to be called by anyone at all whether they have AWS IAM Credentials or are logged in.

The second statement allows anonymous read but only for a specific prefix.

If you want to allow a logged in user to perform the action you have the following choices:

- Control this server side using an [IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) (or [IAM User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html) only if your application is not in AWS). Give the policy attached to the entity the permission to perform putObject, if you want to lock down the bucket further in the principal you can specify the IAM Arn.
- Have you user [login](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html) with an attached [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) user, by logging in with Cognito your frontend/backend will be given temporary session credentials. With these credentials you can interact with the [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/), but be sure that a user has logged in first.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Those are good options and secure but here's my thinking. For option 1: I don't really want to be the middleman here and add a latency in the uploads while also adding to the servers responsibility of handling file uploads and errors that come along with it. 

For option 2: this looks promising but this could possibly lock me in with aws and would make it really difficult for me to cherry pick differnet providers given that my auth is now typed up with asset management as well

Comment: No problem looks like @JohnRotenstein is more appropriate for your use case, have a great day :)